# How can I make simple launcher for FiveM server?

Tags: server, launcher

I would like to know how to create simple launcher for FiveM server. I don't need help about UI, design, etc. only script when someone clicks 'Play' it connects him to server. Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. It would help to know what have you tried so far or what part of the specific difficulty you've encountered.

Comment: I tried something like: public void PlayGame (){ Process.Start(fivem://connect/ip:port) }

Comment: That would be good into to edit into your question. Also include what part seemed to not work & what it was doing instead of functioning as expected.